# Scope dependency resolution to the declaring assembly

Tags: c#, plugins, dependency-injection, autofac

Morning all.

Short version;  all concrete implementations from all assemblies that implement my commonly defined IMenuItem interface are injected into all constructors that require `IEnumerable<IMenuItem>`.

I'm building a small Windows TrayIcon application core that allows plugins.  The core discovers all plugins in the bin directory and creates my Autofac container.

I have a `Core.Interfaces` project that declares an `IMenuItem` interface

Each plugin is defined in its own assembly and within that plugin, there can be many features;  each feature will declare it's menu items.

At runtime, each plugin discovers all features and queries for its menu items.  The issue I am having is that plugin A is receiving menu items from plugin B because all menu items implement the `IMenuItem` interface.

What I'm looking to achieve is to have a common `IMenuItem` interface but when a constructor in plugin A ask's for an `IEnumerable<IMenuItem>` it should only be passed the concretes that we discovered in its own assembly.

Just to say that if I declare the IMenuItem interface in each assembly then this all works just fine, presumably because the registrations are then namespaced to the interface.

I'm struggling for the correct terminology to google this but I think I understand this is a registration issue; perhaps one that I can only solve at resolution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box there's nothing that does this. You'll have to write custom code.

Much of the custom code is going to depend on how you resolve the set of plugins. Here are a couple of options to solve the issue, though if neither of them work for your current design, maybe you can use them to spur your imagination for additional ideas.

*Disclaimer: I'm not running all these through a compiler. They'll be partial examples and I may typo something. Some may be pseudocode. YMMV.*

**Option 1: Register Each Plugin in a Separate Lifetime Scope**

This is how [the multitenant support works](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Multitenant). Basically, the root container has only shared components in it and each plugin (and respective menu items) would be registered in a child scope.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// register common stuff that all plugins use
builder.Register<SomethingCommon>().As<ICommonService>();
var container = builder.Build();

// iterate over the assemblies and create scopes per plugin
var pluginScopes = new List<ILifetimeScope>();
foreach(var assembly in GetThePluginAssemblies())
{
  var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b =>
  {
    b.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IPlugin))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    b.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IMenuItem))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
  });
  pluginScopes.Add(scope);
}
```

At this point, you have a list of separate scopes that you can use to resolve each plugin, like if you needed all the plugins:

```cs
var plugins = pluginScopes.SelectMany(s => s.Resolve<IEnumerable<IPlugin>>());
```

(I *think* that's how SelectMany works, I always get confused. The point is you'd get a flattened list of all the plugins across all scopes.)

To make your life easy, technically you could use the `Autofac.Multitenant` package and "pretend" that each plugin is a separate tenant. It already has all the scope tracking and configuration per tenant built.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// register common stuff that all plugins use
builder.Register<SomethingCommon>().As<ICommonService>();
var container = builder.Build();

// You probably won't want to resolve things "as a tenant" from the container,
// so you'd only use the Multitenant.ApplicationContainer (for global/common stuff)
// or individual tenant scopes directly. The tenant ID strategy, ostensibly, won't
// be used, so just make a dummy one that always returns false or something.
var multiPluginContainer = new MultitenantContainer(container, SomeTenantIdentificationStrategy);

// iterate over the assemblies and create tenants per plugin
// where the tenant ID is something like the assembly name
foreach(var assembly in GetThePluginAssemblies())
{
  multiPluginContainer.ConfigureTenant(assembly.FullName, b =>
  {
    b.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IPlugin))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    b.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IMenuItem))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
  });
}
```

Then you could get the list of plugins ("tenants") and resolve.

```cs
var plugins = multiPluginContainer
  .GetTenants()
  .SelectMany(k =>
    multiPluginContainer.GetTenantScope(k).Resolve<IEnumerable<IPlugin>>());
```

**Option 2: Use Metadata to Tag Items**

Autofac supports [parameters during registration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html) and the `ResolvedParameter` is pretty powerful. Some clever work with that can go a long way.

First, you could register all the menu items and tag them with metadata.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// register a bunch of stuff and...
foreach(var assembly in GetThePluginAssemblies())
{
  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IPlugin))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IMenuItem))
     .WithMetadata("assembly", assembly.FullName)
     .AsImplementedInterfaces();
}
```

OK, now you have all the `IMenuItem` entries tagged with the assembly name. Create a module that automatically attaches a resolved parameter to every `IPlugin` such that any `IEnumerable<IMenuItem>` will be fulfilled by your parameter. This is largely based on the [log4net module example from the docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html).

```cs
public class MenuItemModule : Autofac.Module
{
  private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
      new[]
      {
        new ResolvedParameter(
            // Only provide values for IEnumerable<IMenuItem> requested
            // by IPlugin implementations
            (pi, ctx) =>
               pi.ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<IMenuItem>) &&
               pi.Member.DeclaringType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IPlugin)),
            // Resolve the appropriately tagged menu items
            // IEnumerable<T> - get all the menu items
            // Meta<T> - you want to look at the metadata
            // Lazy<T> - don't actually construct them until you want them
            // meta.Value = Lazy<T>
            // meta.Value.Value resolves the IMenuItem
            (pi, ctx) => {
              var asmName = pi.Member.DeclaringType.Assembly.FullName;
              return ctx.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<IMenuItem>>>>()
                 .Where(meta => meta.Metadata["assembly"] == asmName)
                 .Select(meta => meta.Value.Value);
            }
        ),
      });
  }

  protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
  {
    registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
  }
}
```

You'd then register that module to ensure all resolutions get that parameter.

```cs
builder.RegisterModule<MenuItemModule>();
```

**There are other options.**

You could imagine other permutations on it. Separate container per plugin (which isn't a bad idea - good isolation of plugins). Separate *AppDomain* per plugin (even better isolation but work to marshal data). Base `IPlugin` implementation that has the filtering logic in that instead of in a `ResolvedParameter`. Metadata filter attributes on plugin implementations to do the filtering.

Hopefully this helps unblock you.